# android custom action bar view with home button

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-custom-view

hello guys i have a big problem with my custom action bar and i can't resolve it by long time, can someone show me my feils

i need such action bar

[image: Needed action bar with custom home button]

my customActionBarLayout is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/action_bar_background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/actionBarLogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:src="@drawable/action_bar_logo" />

</LinearLayout>
```

in such way i trying to add it to actionbar

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        android.app.ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar);
        return true;
    }
```

and i have so bad result

[image: bad result =(]

any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

to

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

and use `ImageView` for showing the vertical lines on left of `ActionBar`

Comment: and in what activity i must inflate this image and add action lister ?